# Apache - ScriptAlias: Command not found

Tags: apache

When I try to run the command ScriptAlias, I always get the error:
ScriptAlias: command not found
I have made sure that the alias mod is enabled through a2enmod alias, and I have ran apt-get update a few times as well. Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I did not understand how the module worked, and was trying to use the command directly into the command line. I needed to edit the 000-default.conf file instead.